# Call method before ScriptableObject's OnEnable

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to execute a script before **OnEnable** of the **ScriptableObjects** are called? I tried **RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSplashScreen** and **RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad**, but they are called after **OnEnable**.

Comment: Awake() is called before OnEnable(). Why not simply using it?

Comment: I have the sneaking suspicion that you have the [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. Is running code before OnEnable on a ScriptableObject your end goal, or are you using it to try to solve a different problem?

Comment: I want to be able to update my binary data (game progress) format, but I need to do that before the OnEnable method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Awake()`, [which is called on scripts before OnEnable](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

Note that these messages work slightly *differently* on ScriptableObjects than on MonoBehaviours - there's a good [thread over at Unity's forums discussing ScriptableObject events](https://forum.unity.com/threads/scriptableobject-behaviour-discussion-how-scriptable-objects-work.541212/).